# Online Reader: Text box does not display vertical text [writing-mode:vertical-rl]

Tags: css, user-agent

I am trying to make an Online Reader for Japanese. The problem is that the Text box does not display vertical text [writing-mode:vertical-rl]

Here is the index html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Reader</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="text-area">
      <textarea id="my-textarea" placeholder="Paste your text here"></textarea>
      <textarea id="synchronized-textarea" readonly></textarea>
    </div>
    <button id="lock-button">Lock</button>
    <button id="unlock-button">Unlock</button>
    <div class="options">
      <label for="font-size-slider">Font Size:</label>
      <label for="audio-upload">Upload Audio:</label>
      <input type="file" id="audio-upload">
      <button id="play-button" disabled>Play Audio</button>
      <button id="rewind-button" disabled>Rewind</button>
      <button id="forward-button" disabled>Forward</button>
      <label for="font-size-slider">Font Size (Original Text):</label>
      <input type="range" id="font-size-slider" min="12" max="60" step="2" value="16">
      <label for="synchronized-font-size-slider">Font Size (Synchronized Text):</label>
      <input type="range" id="synchronized-font-size-slider" min="12" max="60" step="2" value="16">
      <!-- Rest of your options elements -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <audio id="audioPlayer" controls>
    <source id="audioSource" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
  </audio>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is style sheet:

```
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
}

/* Override the user agent styles for textarea */
textarea {
  writing-mode: unset !important;
}

.text-area textarea {
  font-size: 28px;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: upright;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  resize: none;
  overflow-wrap: normal;
}

.options {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.options label {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.options input[type="range"] {
  width: 150px;
}

/* Add styles for audio control buttons */
#play-button,
#rewind-button,
#forward-button {
  padding: 8px 12px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #007bff;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#play-button:hover,
#rewind-button:hover,
#forward-button:hover {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

/* Disable audio control buttons when they are disabled */
#play-button[disabled],
#rewind-button[disabled],
#forward-button[disabled] {
  background-color: #ccc;
  cursor: default;
}
```

Here is js:

```
// JavaScript code goes here

// Font Size Adjustment
function adjustFontSize(textarea, slider) {
  textarea.style.fontSize = `${slider.value}px`;
}

const fontSizeSlider = document.getElementById('font-size-slider');
const synchronizedFontSizeSlider = document.getElementById('synchronized-font-size-slider');
const audioUpload = document.getElementById('audio-upload');
const playButton = document.getElementById('play-button');
const rewindButton = document.getElementById('rewind-button');
const forwardButton = document.getElementById('forward-button');
const audioPlayer = document.getElementById('audioPlayer');
const myTextarea = document.getElementById('my-textarea');
const synchronizedTextarea = document.getElementById('synchronized-textarea');
let isPlaying = false;
let isSynchronizedLocked = false; // Flag to track if synchronization is locked

fontSizeSlider.addEventListener('input', () => {
  adjustFontSize(myTextarea, fontSizeSlider);
});

synchronizedFontSizeSlider.addEventListener('input', () => {
  adjustFontSize(synchronizedTextarea, synchronizedFontSizeSlider);
});

// Function to enable or disable audio control buttons based on audio playback state
function enableAudioButtons(enabled) {
  playButton.disabled = !enabled;
  rewindButton.disabled = !enabled;
  forwardButton.disabled = !enabled;
}

// Audio Upload and Playback
audioUpload.addEventListener('change', () => {
  handleAudioUpload();
});

function handleAudioUpload() {
  const audioFile = audioUpload.files[0];
  if (audioFile) {
    const audioURL = URL.createObjectURL(audioFile);
    audioPlayer.src = audioURL;
    enableAudioButtons(true);
  }
}

// Audio Control Functions
function toggleAudioPlayback() {
  if (isPlaying) {
    audioPlayer.pause();
  } else {
    audioPlayer.play();
  }
  isPlaying = !isPlaying;
}

function rewindAudio(seconds) {
  audioPlayer.currentTime -= seconds;
}

function forwardAudio(seconds) {
  audioPlayer.currentTime += seconds;
}

playButton.addEventListener('click', toggleAudioPlayback);
rewindButton.addEventListener('click', () => rewindAudio(5)); // Rewind 5 seconds
forwardButton.addEventListener('click', () => forwardAudio(5)); // Forward 5 seconds

// Text Synchronization
document.addEventListener('paste', handlePasteEvent);
myTextarea.addEventListener('input', handleInputEvent);

function handlePasteEvent(event) {
  if (!isSynchronizedLocked) {
    const clipboardData = event.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
    const pastedText = clipboardData.getData('text');

    // Update the content of the synchronized text box with the pasted text
    synchronizedTextarea.value = pastedText;
  }
}

function handleInputEvent(event) {
  if (!isSynchronizedLocked) {
    const typedText = event.target.value;

    // Update the content of the synchronized text box with the typed text
    synchronizedTextarea.value = typedText;
  }
}

// Locking and Unlocking Text Synchronization
document.getElementById('lock-button').addEventListener('click', lockSynchronizedTextarea);
document.getElementById('unlock-button').addEventListener('click', unlockSynchronizedTextarea);

function lockSynchronizedTextarea() {
  isSynchronizedLocked = true;
  synchronizedTextarea.setAttribute('readonly', 'true');
}

function unlockSynchronizedTextarea() {
  isSynchronizedLocked = false;
  synchronizedTextarea.removeAttribute('readonly');
}

// Rest of your audio-related functions here
// ...
```

But the writing mode does not show vertical

here is the inspect element

```
element.style {
}
.text-area textarea {
    font-size: 28px;
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    text-orientation: upright;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    resize: none;
    overflow-wrap: normal;
}
textarea {
    writing-mode: unset !important;
}
user agent stylesheet
textarea {
    writing-mode: horizontal-tb !important;
    font-style: ;
    font-variant-ligatures: ;
    font-variant-caps: ;
    font-variant-numeric: ;
    font-variant-east-asian: ;
    font-variant-alternates: ;
    font-weight: ;
    font-stretch: ;
    font-size: ;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-optical-sizing: ;
    font-kerning: ;
    font-feature-settings: ;
    font-variation-settings: ;
    text-rendering: auto;
    color: fieldtext;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-indent: 0px;
    text-shadow: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: start;
    appearance: auto;
    -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
    resize: auto;
    cursor: text;
    white-space-collapse: preserve;
    text-wrap: wrap;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    background-color: field;
    column-count: initial !important;
    margin: 0em;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: -internal-light-dark(rgb(118, 118, 118), rgb(133, 133, 133));
    border-image: initial;
    padding: 2px;
}
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

I want the text to be shown vertical from right to left as this is a reader for Japanese